# Create a policy cloud formation

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

Does anyone know how to create a policy using cloud formation and then have another cloud formation template that assigns that policy to a role?

I'm looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html and that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

The link between a policy and a role is declared in the `AWS::IAM::Policy` resource. So, for instance, you can have one stack [export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) the role and another stack import it using the intrinsic function [Fn::ImportValue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) and link it to a policy resource.

Exporting stack:

```
Resources:
  myRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      Properties:
        ... 
Outputs:
  exportedRole:
    Value: !Ref myRole
    Export:
      Name: "myExportedRole"
```

Importing stack:

```
Resources:
  myPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !ImportValue myExportedRole
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the role and the policy at the same time. Here is an example:

```
    "LambdaFunctionRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": [
                                "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                            ]
                        },
                        "Action": [
                            "sts:AssumeRole"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Path": "/",
            "Policies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "AlexaSkillCloudWatchLogsAccess",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Sid": "AllowLogging",
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                                ],
                                "Resource": [
                                    "*"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

This resource creates a policy for a Lambda function with a policy included. Then you can include the ARN of the role in a lambda function in the same template with "Fn::GetAtt"